# Is it possible to create false positives, aka "throwing exception" on purpose in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, exceptions

I've been playing with this over the past weekend and it seems impossible, I guess since it's considered a big security issue if it was possible. Example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

1. msg.sender sends something;
2. contract waits for confirmation if tx succeeds;
3. if tx does/doesn't: do something

Challenge: claim tx failed despite success...example of one of my attempts so far:

```
// this is the contract that we call 
contract richkid{

function buy_ceo_place() public payable returns (bool)

{

if(msg.sender.send(this.balance))

{

return false;

}
sorry-failed() //some function that handles in case send above had failed
return true;

}

}
```

this is the 'malicious' contract on the msg.sender side that we used to call the contract above, this is a contract with payable fallback:

```
contract receiver{

function () external payable //fixed on suggestion by @goodvibration

{

//try to forward to someone
address someone = 0x.......
someone.send(msg.value);

//claim it failed using assembly because why not:

assembly

{

invalid

}

}

}
```

In this case the invalid assembly opcode simply reverts everything to the EOA, that is no state changes only gas seems to be wasted (not sure about the gas). I've tried with delegatecall to the contract and with throw or currently think what will happen if the fallback calls back using zero gas after the send say: call.gas(0).value(0) - will likely fail since gasless txes will not be mined? Thanx!

Comment: Without implementing `function() external payable` in your malicious contract, your call to `msg.sender.send` will always return `false`. If you did implement this function in that contract, then please show the relevant code. More generally, please post a piece of code which actually compiles (instead of those "broken" code fragments which you posted up there).

Comment: surely you can compile it?? It's no brainer to just work it out, I mean I am just giving pieces of functions to highlight the issues, not going to give whole solutions. I even deployed it on ropsten successfully last night...just curious if it's possible overall something remotely similar.

Comment: I'm not asking you for a whole solution, I am asking you to post ALL the code relevant to your question and ONLY the code relevant to your question. Those code fragments (totally unaligned by the way) are: 1. hard to read. 2. hard to make sense from, in conjunction with your question. 3. not abiding the rules of this website which state that you should provide a minimal-working example.

Comment: OK I made it 'external'...if it wasn't working then how is ropsten getting money on it? The goal was for the payable function to accept ether not return false/true seeing how according to remix a payable fallback cannot return true/false value which makes your initial suggestion even more debatable but none of this is related to my question anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't have to be external (public is also OK). I did not see any payable function when I initially viewed your post (possibly because the entire code wasn't aligned in a proper way, making it rather difficult to read and quickly grasp.

Comment: As to your other note - if the fallback function reverts then the `send` which has triggered it returns `false`. Otherwise it returns `true`. And again, regardless of what your question is, please organize the code in it in a readable manner.

Comment: Side note: you might wanna read about the 2300 gas stipend that a fallback function is limited to when invoked via `send` or `transfer` from another contract.

Comment: OK I admit my questions recently are too confusing and may be simplified. OK, by the way this may be equally "devastating" if it works when it's called by call (I assume 34050 gass as with the call method).